# Grub Install erro r fixed but how to access Windows?

Tags: grub2, system-installation, grub-efi

I tried to double boot install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on computer with Legacy boot. In Windows partition manager I allocated 40Gb free space and then procedeed with installing Ubuntu.

1. From the free space created that way I created ~ 21GB ext4 with '/' mount point
2. From rest I assigned partition as swap area

after that I encountered grub-install error. I followed this tutorial to solve it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fleF4qDtwDE

TL:DR from tutorial

1. I reset instalation and chose "try ubuntu"
2. Installed boot-repair and followed steps for legacy boot

Now ubuntu works fine, but how do I access Windows? Do boot-repair explicitly somehow wiped clean all memory storage despite allocating previously only 40GB for ubuntu?

Pls help

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** What version of the Ubuntu OS are you trying to install (please edit your question to include this), as this will help the community with resolving your issue. Thanks